# UITableViewCell constraints breaking when adding a new cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewController` that a combinations of 3 different cell types. I have an odd bug that occurs when pushing a new cell to the table view and calling reload data.

This is my table view, before it breaks
[image]

At this point, 2 new cells are added and `reloadData` is called.
[image]

As you can see the highlighted cell now has wildly incorrect constraints and in fact scrolling up and down in the simulator causes other cells to break. As if the issue jumps from cell to cell randomly.

The console does output a debug error, however I am unsure how to make heads or tails of this

```
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000201ccd0 UIImageView:0x7ffb7bd4d740.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x600003a79ea0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000201c3c0 UIView:0x7ffb7bd4d970.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600003a79ea0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 15   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020194a0 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffb7bd4d740]-(15)-[UIView:0x7ffb7bd4d970]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002012d50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffb7bd53580.width == 375   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000201d7c0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(16)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003a79ea0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffb7bd53580 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000201c690 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600003a79ea0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(16)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffb7bd53580 )>"
)
```

I set my constraints programmatically, there are no storyboards or nibs in this view.

I would really appreciate some guidance or direction as to how to fix this.

```
   private let chatCellId = "chatCellId"
    private let mediaCellId = "mediaCellId"
    private let ctaCellId = "ctaCellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: chatCellId)
        tableView.register(MediaMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: mediaCellId)
        tableView.register(CTAMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ctaCellId)

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300

        viewModel.reloadData = { [unowned self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.reloadTableView()
            }
        }

        viewModel.fetchBotResponse(byKey: "welcome")
        vc.delegate = self

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellType = viewModel.messages[indexPath.row].type

        if cellType == .media {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: mediaCellId, for: indexPath) as! MediaMessageCell
            cell.content = viewModel.messages[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else if cellType == .callToAction {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ctaCellId, for: indexPath) as! CTAMessageCell
            cell.content = viewModel.messages[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: chatCellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
            cell.content = viewModel.messages[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

ChatMessageCell

extension ChatMessageCell {

```
fileprivate func anchorViews() -> Void {
    let marginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    [avatar, messageBackground].forEach { addSubview($0) }
    messageBackground.insertSubview(messageText, at: 0)

    if content?.origin == .system {
        let avatarInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        let avatarSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        avatar.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "large_bot_head")
        avatar.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: avatarInsets, size: avatarSize)

        let messageBackgroundInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        messageBackground.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: avatar.trailingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: messageBackgroundInsets)

        let messageTextInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
        messageText.anchor(top: messageBackground.topAnchor, leading: messageBackground.leadingAnchor, bottom: messageBackground.bottomAnchor, trailing: messageBackground.trailingAnchor, padding: messageTextInsets)
    } else {            
        avatar.image = UIImage.from(color: UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "00f5ff"))
        messageBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "00f5ff")
        messageBackground.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]

        let avatarInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        let avatarSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        avatar.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "large_bot_head")
        avatar.anchor(top: marginGuide.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: avatarInsets, size: avatarSize)

        let messageBackgroundInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        messageBackground.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: avatar.leadingAnchor, padding: messageBackgroundInsets)

        let messageTextInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
        messageText.anchor(top: messageBackground.topAnchor, leading: messageBackground.leadingAnchor, bottom: messageBackground.bottomAnchor, trailing: messageBackground.trailingAnchor, padding: messageTextInsets)
    }
}
```

}

CTAMessageCell

```
extension CTAMessageCell {
    fileprivate func anchorViews() -> Void {
        let marginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        [avatar, messageBackground].forEach { contentView.addSubview($0) }
        messageBackground.insertSubview(messageText, at: 0)
        messageBackground.insertSubview(buttonStackView, at: 0)

        let avatarInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        let avatarSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        avatar.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "large_bot_head")
        avatar.anchor(top: marginGuide.topAnchor, leading: marginGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: avatarInsets, size: avatarSize)

        let messageBackgroundInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        messageBackground.anchor(top: marginGuide.topAnchor, leading: avatar.trailingAnchor, bottom: marginGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: messageBackgroundInsets)

        let messageTextInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        messageText.anchor(top: messageBackground.topAnchor, leading: messageBackground.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: messageBackground.trailingAnchor, padding: messageTextInsets)

        let buttonStackViewInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 10, right: 15)
        buttonStackView.anchor(top: messageText.bottomAnchor, leading: messageBackground.leadingAnchor, bottom: messageBackground.bottomAnchor, trailing: messageBackground.trailingAnchor, padding: buttonStackViewInsets)

    }
}
```

I anchor with the following extension

```
 func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> AnchoredConstraints {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()

        if let top = top {
            anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            anchoredConstraints.trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.width = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.height = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        }

        [anchoredConstraints.top, anchoredConstraints.leading, anchoredConstraints.bottom, anchoredConstraints.trailing, anchoredConstraints.width, anchoredConstraints.height].forEach{ $0?.isActive = true }

        return anchoredConstraints
    }
```

Comment: “pushing a new cell to the table view” What does that even mean? Show your code!

Comment: Can you add some source code? At least cellForRowAtIndexPath would be useful. Also, remember that UITableView reuses table cells when you scroll, chech that you don't add duplicate views and that you set the correct reuse label to ensure that the system doesn't reuse cells of the wrong type

Comment: I am just adding code now, apologies.

Comment: I have added some further code

Comment: Still not enough relevant code. What does `cell.content = viewModel.messages[indexPath.row]` do? If you omit it does the problem go away?

Comment: cell.content = viewModel.messages[indexPath.row] sets the content variable within the cell using the properties on my viewModel.messages array. content has a didSet property that applies the relevant values. If I omit it, nothing happens as the cell does not have any content

Comment: So is the problem for just one cell type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three constraints are in conflict:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000201ccd0 UIImageView:0x7ffb7bd4d740.trailing == 
UILayoutGuide:0x600003a79ea0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000201c3c0 UIView:0x7ffb7bd4d970.leading == 
UILayoutGuide:0x600003a79ea0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 15   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020194a0 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffb7bd4d740]-(15)- 
[UIView:0x7ffb7bd4d970]   (active)>",
```

The second constraint and the third constraint pin the leading edge of the view to different places. But it is unclear from the code you have posted why this is the case.

I'm guessing that cell reusability has tripped you up. Consider ChatMessageCell above. If the same cell has been reused, and `content?.origin == .system` is true the first time, but not the second time, you will end up with constraints from both paths and this will cause constraint issues - unless you remove or deactivate the unneeded constraints (in `prepareForReuse` for example).

Also: https://www.wtfautolayout.com/ makes it much easier to visualise Apple's constraint logs.